# Header button with icon in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have created a sample app using ReactNative. And I have used ReactNative Navigation for navigation (Stack Navigation). It has only 2 screens. Home and Detail screen. I was able to implement Stack navigation successfully. However I'm having issues adding an icon for header button in right side of header title. To add header button with icon I used a third party library called HeaderButtons. However when I render, it only shows the title not the icon. Please note that I have used expo to create reactnative project and icons from @expo/vector-icons.

thanks in advance,
Yohan

// This is custom header component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Platform } from "react-native";
import { HeaderButton } from "react-navigation-header-buttons";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons";


const CustomHeaderButton = (props) => {
  return (
    <HeaderButton
      {...props}
      IconComponent={Ionicons}
      iconSize={23}
      color={Platform.OS === "android" ? "white" : "blue"}
    />
  );
};

export default CustomHeaderButton;
```

// This is the root navigation

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Button} from'react-native'
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

// import screens
import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";
import DetailScreen from "../screens/DetailScreen";

import { HeaderButtons, Item } from "react-navigation-header-buttons";
import  {HeaderButton}  from "../component/HeaderButton";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function StackNavigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          headerRight: ()=>(
            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
             <Item
               title="Header"
               iconName="ios-search"
               onPress={() => {
                 alert("Button clicked");
               }}
             />
           </HeaderButtons> 
         ),
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={DetailScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default StackNavigator;
```

Comment: I seem to be having the same issue.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: Also running into what i believe is the same issue.  A solution would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: @AndrewB. did u get it fixed ?

Comment: Yes the issue was stemming from mixing both react-native-navigation 4.0 and 5.0.

Answer (score 4):

I asked this question months ago. and now I'm going to answer my own question. We can use headerRight property in ReactNavigation as per the documentation.
here is an example

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Button} from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

// components
import AddCart from '../components/AddCart';

// screens
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import ProductsScreen from '../screens/ProductsScreen';
import ProductDetailsScreen from '../screens/ProductDetailsScreen';
import CartScreen from '../screens/Cart';
import UserLocationMapScreen from '../screens/Map/MapScreen';
import OrderConfirmationScreen from '../screens/Order/OrderConfirmationScreen';
import AuthNavigator from '../navigation/AuthNavigator';
import CartNavigator from '../navigation/CartNavigator';

import defaultStyles from '../config/style';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const ProductNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={({navigation}) => ({
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: defaultStyles.colors.primaryColor,
        },
        headerTintColor: defaultStyles.colors.whiteColor,
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
        headerRight: () => (
          <AddCart
            name="cart"
            iconColor={defaultStyles.colors.whiteColor}
            backgroundColor={defaultStyles.colors.primaryColor}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Cart')}
          />
        ),
      })}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{title: 'Quickee - Categories'}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="All_Products"
        component={ProductsScreen}
        options={({route}) => (
          {
            title:route.params.categoryName
          }
        )}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Product_Details"
        component={ProductDetailsScreen}
        options={{title: ''}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Cart"
        component={CartScreen}
        options={{title: 'Shopping Cart', headerRight: ''}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="User_Location"
        component={UserLocationMapScreen}
        options={{title: 'Pick Your Delivery Location', headerRight: ''}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Order_Confirmation"
        component={OrderConfirmationScreen}
        options={{
          title: 'Order Confirmation',
          headerRight: '',
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Auth"
        component={AuthNavigator}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default ProductNavigator;
```

Note. screenOptions property requires an object or a function that returns an object

[here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers) is the documentation for react navigation 5v header configuration